# tidyr::spread resulting in multiple rows

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I have a similar problem than the following, but the solution presented in the following link does not work for me: 
[tidyr spread does not aggregate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370885/tidyr-spread-does-not-aggregate-data)

I have a df in the following structure:

```
    UndesiredIndex  DesiredIndex    DesiredRows Result
1   x1A x1  A   50,32
2   x1B x2  B   7,34
3   x2A x1  A   50,33
4   x2B x2  B   7,35
```

Using the code below:

```
  dftest <- bd_teste %>%
  select(-UndesiredIndex) %>%
  spread(DesiredIndex, Result)
```

I expected the following result:

```
DesiredIndex    A   B
A   50,32   50,33
B   7,34    7,35
```

Although, I keep getting the following result:

```
    DesiredIndex    x1  x2
1   A   50.32   NA
2   B   7.34    NA
3   A   NA  50.33
4   B   NA  7.35
```

PS: Sometimes I force the column UndesiredIndex out with `select(-UndesiredIndex)`, but I keep getting the following message:

Adding missing grouping variables: `UndesiredIndex`

Might be something easy to stack those rows, but I'm new to R and have been trying so hard to solve this but without success.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `aggregate(Result~DesiredRows,dat,paste)`. First ensure that your columns are not factors but rather characters

Comment: Try `df1 %>% select(-UndesiredIndex) %>% group_by(DesiredIndex) %>% mutate(new =LETTERS[row_number()]) %>% ungroup %>% select(-DesiredRows) %>% spread(DesiredIndex, Result)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks in advance for your help, but the proposed solution returns that the dat argument was not found. Should I fill it with my df's name?

Comment: @akrun In advance, Thanks for your help, but unfortunately, it ended up with the same result.

Comment: Based on the input you showed, it is giving me the expected output

Comment: dat is your data. I don't know you called you called your data

Comment: @akrun That's weird. I copied-pasted your solution, and it kept giving me NA and not stacking the columns. I can't get what could be wrong. Thanks again for the time to answer.

Comment: Please check the output below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by `DesiredIndex`, create a sequence column and then do the `spread`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
    select(-UndesiredIndex) %>% 
    group_by(DesiredIndex) %>% 
    mutate(new = LETTERS[row_number()]) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(-DesiredIndex) %>% 
    spread(new, Result)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  DesiredRows A     B    
#  <chr>       <chr> <chr>
#1 A           50,32 50,33
#2 B           7,34  7,35
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(
    list(
        UndesiredIndex = c("x1A", "x1B", "x2A", "x2B"), 
        DesiredIndex = c("x1", "x2", "x1", "x2"), 
        DesiredRows = c("A", "B", "A", "B"), 
        Result = c("50,32", "7,34", "50,33", "7,35")
    ), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4")
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun. It didn't work in my original df, but it did work when inputted here.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter, but more theoretically round-about.

## Data

(Thanks to @akrun!)

```
df1 <- structure(
    list(
        UndesiredIndex = c("x1A", "x1B", "x2A", "x2B"), 
        DesiredIndex = c("x1", "x2", "x1", "x2"), 
        DesiredRows = c("A", "B", "A", "B"), 
        Result = c("50,32", "7,34", "50,33", "7,35")
    ), 
    class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4")
)
```

This is a great technique for concatenating rows.

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(DesiredRows) %>% 
  summarise(Result = paste(Result, collapse = "|")) %>% #<Concatenate rows
  separate(Result, into = c("A", "B"), sep = "\\|")     #<Separate by '|'

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   DesiredRows A     B    
#>   <chr>       <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A           50,32 50,33
#> 2 B           7,34  7,35
```

Created on 2018-08-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).