# R, tidyverse: How to use spread() together with group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have data in long format and am trying to `spread` data to long format `group_by` an identifier. I have tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370885/tidyr-spread-does-not-aggregate-data) and and receive this error message `Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator`. I have also tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259380/spread-with-duplicate-identifiers-using-tidyverse-and).

My dataset looks like this;

```
iden<-c(rep(1:25, 2), rep(26:50, 2))
group<-c(rep(5, 25), rep(20, 25), rep(-18, 25), rep(-80, 25))
value<-sample(100:5000, 100, replace=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(iden, group, value)
```

Please help me figure out how to get the data in wide format without duplicate identifiers
[(see attched image here for expected output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwyjz.png).

For image of @Ronak Shah's answer see  [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyAjo.png)

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried? What is the expected output that you are looking for?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(iden = row_number()) %>% spread(group, value)`. `spread` has been retired and replaced by `pivot_wider` instead.

Comment: @Ronak Shah. I tried; ```df %>% 
  group_by(iden) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(-unique) %>%
  spread(group, value) %>%
  select(-id)``` and ```df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  spread(group, value) %>% 
  select(iden, group, value)```. Your code almost works! I'm looking for there to be 50 observations (rows) with values in two of the new columns per row. Thanks so much for helping out!

Comment: Can you update your post to show first few rows of expected output?

Comment: @Ronak Shah. I have added an image of expected output. I tried the solution in the post my question is similar to, but it does not use ```spread``` (or ```pivot_wider```), and it did not work for me. Thank you helping me.

Comment: Sorry but I think my answer gives you the same expected output as shown in the image. It has unique `iden` as one column and 4 columns with 5, 20, -18, -80.

Comment: @Ronak Shah. If I run this code; ```Ronak<-df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(iden = row_number()) %>% spread(group, value)``` then, ```head(Ronak)```,  I get the image added to my edited question. So there is data being incorrectly spread to values that don't exist. I hope this helps.